# NavigationViem item is not checked

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I manage to build navigation drawer with five fragments.. the fragment switched fine when navigation item clicked but then i create button in home fragment to navigate to other fragment.. fragment swicthed fine.. but supportActionBar title did not change as fragment is changed.. then i put this in fragmentTwo

`((MainActivity)getActivity).getSupportActionBar.setTitle("fragmentTwo");`

So actionBarTitle change as fragment change.. but.. the navigation item in navigation drawer is not checked.. i find that i have to

*get NavigationView from MainActivity in fragment*

how can we do this?

Can you guys share how to get navigationView from MainActivity in fragment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635653/access-parent-fragment-method-from-child-fragment?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa <-- this maybe help you

Comment: Thx a lot.. checking it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer was posted by Op as an edit in the body of their question:*

I did this to handle navigation from Button in home fragment:

```
NavigationView navView = (NavigationView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navView);
navView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
```